# Get the respective country code as well as IP address using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am currently working in ASP.Net project and am stuck where I have to get the Country Name as well as the IP address of the Particular Computer who is visiting my website.

I have tried this

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function (location) 
{
    alert(location.country_name);
});
```

But it is giving me only about India and I need for all country.

Comment: _Plzzzzzz help me google_ hmmmmm, Use `location.ip` to get the IP

Comment: bcozzz your are opening your website in india so it gives only india country. use vpnoneclick you can find the other countries also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is based on the country you make the request from based on the IP address. If you are testing in India, that is all you will see. Personally, I see `United Kingdom` as the country name; in fact, here is my full response:

```
{
    "ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", // redacted
    "country_code": "GB",
    "country_name": "United Kingdom",
    "region_code": "",
    "region_name": "",
    "city": "",
    "zipcode": "",
    "latitude": 51.5,
    "longitude": -0.13,
    "metro_code": "",
    "area_code": ""
}
```

---

> But i want to see all the visitor of my website. User cant see his own location. If u r hitting from United Kingdom then i get the details like from this country_name,City,and Ip is visted ur Website

I which case you need to use AJAX to get the client to send their country data to your server when the IP lookup has completed. Something like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function (location) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://yourwebsite/tracking/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: location, // or you could create a new object with only the properties you need
        success: function(response) {
            // it worked.
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // it didn't work
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx Rory for ur ans But i want to see all the visitor of my website. User cant see his own location. If u r hitting from United Kingdom then i get the details like from this country_name,City,and Ip is visted ur Website...

Comment: @Vishnu:You need to save these data in your database, and create a page which fetch these data from database

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank u so much i got it now. it showing me the all details. Thank U